# Global RegExp and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Why does this not work as (I) expected?

```js
var re = /blah/gi;
console.log([
  'blah-1',
  'blah-2'
].filter(i => re.test(i)))

// expected ["blah-1"], ["blah-2"]
// returns only ["blah-1"]
```

If I remove the global flag, it returns both.

```js
var re = /blah/i;
console.log([
  'blah-1',
  'blah-2'
].filter(i => re.test(i)))
```

It also works if I don't use a variable

```js
console.log([
  'blah-1',
  'blah-2'
].filter(i => /blah/gi.test(i)))
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: thanks @epascarello. I was thinking it had something to do with arrays being converted to string and global searching. didn't realize till hev1 pointed out that the global regex had state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't reuse the regular expression because [`RegularExpression#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) modifies the state of global regular expressions; namely, it will advance the `lastIndex` property past the current match. Instead, you can either use `String#match` or recreate the regular expression on each iteration.

```js
var re = /blah/gi;
console.log([
  'blah-1',
  'blah-2'
].filter(i => i.match(re)));
```